# Keep doing a job after client timeouts / return current progress before timeout

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am writing a Spring-Webflux application which works with downloaded and persisted data.

One use-case is a REST request from a client to trigger the download of data from an external dependency to the application's database and return the total downloaded entries.

I handle this download as a subscription to a `Flux` and respond with a `Mono` containing a json that tells the user how much data was downloaded:

```
http :8080/rest/download from==2019-08-14T00:00:00Z

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "count": 19000
}
```

The used Java code looks like this:

```
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> importDataBetween(Instant from, Instant to) {
    return backendAdapter.importData(from, to)
            .doOnComplete(this::cleanupDb)
            .doOnNext(this::storeData)
            .count()
            .map(count -> Map.of("count", count)); // e.g. { 'count' : 123 }
}
```

Now the problem is, if a client timeouts, the job itself is cancelled:

```
http :8080/rest/download from==2019-08-01T00:00:00Z

http: error: Request timed out (30s).
```

Are there any standard capabilities of webflux to handle such cases?

Is it possible to count the results and after a timeout of e.g. 29s return that number with a remark "the download is still in progress"?

Ideally, if the operation takes less than 30 seconds, the result should be returned, otherwise the current progress or a default response could be returned but the subscription to the download-process should not be cancelled.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities: If you want to prematurely close a connection prior to a client's estimated timeout, you can use `Flux::take` with a reasonable Duration. If you would like to add arbitrary information to the response, use `Flux::buffer` and add custom message to the already buffered objects.

To showcase this, consider the following example:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("flux-take")
    public Flux<Result> fluxTake() {
        Flux<Result> resultFlux = createFlux();
        resultFlux.share().subscribe(result -> log.info("result={}", result));
        return resultFlux.take(Duration.ofMillis(1500));
    }

    @GetMapping("flux-buffer")
    public Mono<BufferedResult> fluxBuffer() {
        Flux<Result> resultFlux = createFlux();
        resultFlux.share().subscribe(result -> log.info("result={}", result));
        return resultFlux.buffer(Duration.ofMillis(1500))
                .next()
                .map(results -> new BufferedResult("Request timed out, returning buffered results", results));
    }

    private Flux<Result> createFlux() {
        return Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300))
                .timed()
                .map(timedId -> new Result(timedId.get(), timedId.elapsed().toMillis()));
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Result {
        private final Integer id;
        private final Long elapsedMillis;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class BufferedResult {
        private final String message;
        private final List<Result> results;
    }
}
```

The result from the client's perspective looks like this:

```
$ http :8080/api/flux-take --timeout=2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
transfer-encoding: chunked

[
    {
        "elapsedMillis": 304,
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "elapsedMillis": 300,
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "elapsedMillis": 304,
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "elapsedMillis": 302,
        "id": 4
    }
]

$ http :8080/api/flux-buffer --timeout=2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 187
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "message": "Request timed out, returning buffered results",
    "results": [
        {
            "elapsedMillis": 301,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "elapsedMillis": 301,
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "elapsedMillis": 302,
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "elapsedMillis": 304,
            "id": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the client's timeout of 2 seconds and the 1500ms timeout within the application. The client will never hit the 2 seconds timeout and always receive a proper response.

IntelliJ will display a hint `Calling 'subscribe' in non-blocking scope` on `resultFlux.share().subscribe(...)` but I couldn't figure out a better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

there are several methods that can solve some of your problems.

you can use `Flux#bufferTimeout(int maxSize, Duration maxTime)`

To buffer up a number of items, end emit when the number of items reaches the maxsize OR it reaches the time given in seconds.

There are several methods, i recommend checking out the flux api timeout and buffer sections to find what works for you.

[Flux API](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html)